# How to handle null for Warning: Operand of null-aware operation

Tags: flutter, dart

`static String lang ='';`

`lang` must be `String` not `String?` because I want to use `lang.contains()`

However My code is like this

```
static String lang ='';
List? languages = [];
languages = await Devicelocale.preferredLanguages;// it returns List<dynamic>
lang = languages![0];
```

It can be compiled but this warning occurs.

```
lib/commonfunc.dart:48:25: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'List<dynamic>' which excludes null. - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
```

How can solve this??

Is it possible to cast `String?` to `String`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a default lang in case there is no preferredLanguages or error occurred like this

```
    static String lang ='';
        List? languages = [];
        languages = await Devicelocale.preferredLanguages;
        if(languages?.isNotEmpty ==true){
           lang = languages[0] ?? "en";
        }else{ 
        lang = "en";
        }
```

Comment: What happens to `lang` if languages is indeed empty? Worse, what happens to `languages.isNotEmpty` is languages is null?

Comment: you need to set a default lang in the else

Answer (score 0):

You should try to never use a `!`. Variables are nullable for a reasons, they *can* be null and your compiler is very good at guiding you through this. Don't try to be smarter than your compiler by using a `!`.

You can use `if`s or null aware operators like `?` or `??`, but don't assume something *cannot* be null, when in reality, it **can** and **will** be. You need to *handle* that situation, not ignore it:

```
String lang ='';
String fallbackLanguage = 'en';

List<dynamic>? languages = await Devicelocale.preferredLanguages;

lang = languages?.first ?? fallbackLanguage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereType<String>` to filter the type you're looking for and create a new list of `List<String>` (non-null).

```dart
final List<dynamic> languages = await Devicelocale.preferredLanguages;
final preferredLangs = languages.whereType<String>();
```

Sample:

```dart
void main() {
  final List<dynamic> fakeSource = ["one", null, "two", "three"];
  final nonNull = fakeSource.whereType<String>();
  
  print(nonNull);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add the bang `!` at the end `languages[0]!` to remove the nullability.

Comment: Using a `!` is meant for those super rare exceptional situations, where you as a programmer *know* it cannot possibly be null, but your compiler cannot prove it. You as a programmer in this instance have no idea whether this could maybe become null, so using a `!` is simply wrong and a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: I know what you mean, however the question was how he can convert a `String?` to `String`, the answer is about that, I don't take the context into consideration, but I see your point.

Comment: Without context, the answer is still flat out wrong. You convert by checking for null and acting accordingly, not by turning the safety features of the compiler off and blindly assuming it is not null.